# how to select the latest insert document in mongodb,

Tags: mongodb

For example, I have a collection called `testing` and having more than 20k documents.

I have inserted a few documents recently, and they got partially inserted (only a few fields got inserted) without throwing any error at a particular time let's say 4 PM IST.
My questions are:

1. what query to use to find the latest insert operation occurs on the `testing` collection using any given field (like timestamp, date, etc.)
2. what are the reasons for the partial update (issue occurs after I upgraded 3.2.4 to 3.2.12)

The same query was used before the upgrade, and it was working fine

Answer (score 2):

Find testing collection with sort option for createdOn (date or timestamp) field,
This will result last inserted Documents.

```
        db.collection.find().sort({createdOn:-1}).limit()
```